# jQuery Validate - Unhighlight error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Validate with Selecter and while highlight is working just fine, unhighlight is not removing the error class.
Code:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("selectcheck", function(value, element, arg){
 return arg != value;
 }, "Invalid");

 $('select').selecter();

 $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(input)" });

 $("form").validate({
   highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
      if(  $(element).is('select') ) {              
        $('.selecter-selected').addClass(errorClass);
      }  else {
      $(element).addClass(errorClass);
      }
   },
   unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
      if(  $(element).is('select') ) {              
        $('.selecter-selected').removeClass(errorClass);
      }  else {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
      }
   },
   rules: {
     selecter: { selectcheck: "default" }
   }
 });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPdxWO